# New datanode not tranferring data from existing hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, datanode

I have followed up the tutriolpoint guide and completed every step on setting up a new node into an existing hadoop cluster. But I am facing difficulty in figuring out why data isn’t being transferred. I finished checking host files and the files related to the authorized key that are supposed to be in the functioning slave node. The data node already contains information on the connection with the master node but isn't transferring the data from the master node. When I try to ping the master node from the new datanode, it's giving an response of no host master found but when I type dfsadmin -report on new node it shows the master node and 4 live slave nodes(doesn't show the new node that I am trying to setup).

I tried checking all the files related to hosts on new and master node and re-saved the IP regarding the new node. And expected the masternode to start transferring data to the node by starting the datanode but the node didn't increse in size and wasn't able to ping the master from the new node.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are using IP addresses instead of domain name.  This is likely the cause of the issue.

Update your (all) you host file to have domain names and fix the domain name of the new node to match.  Then fix your config to match the domain name.

Comment: Thank you after adding the domain names to the IP address it was able to connect to data nodes without causing issues.